# JS How do I get the value out of my method inside my function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, function, methods

```
const getUserCoins = function(firstToUpper) {
    var getUserCoinsSql = `SELECT * FROM roulettetabelle WHERE Name = "${firstToUpper}"`
    
    con.query(getUserCoinsSql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var resultString = JSON.stringify(result);
        var coinsPart = resultString.split(',"')[1]
        coins = parseInt(coinsPart.replace('Coins":', ""));
    });
}
```

Hello I want the function to return the value of coins... I dont understand how to do it

Comment: **WARNING**: Use placeholder values to inject data and stay away from template strings. Most MySQL Drivers for JavaScript support this out of the box.

Comment: Also consider using a Promise-capable database layer like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/). Then you can use `async`/`await` which makes your code easier to follow.